# What does Cross Validated aim to be, who is it for?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, software

There has been a lot of discussion about software-related questions on CV (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1577/1390,) or [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/1390) for examples...). And yet there is *still* no clear idea and guidance on what CV is, what it strives to be and who it is for.

I've been a user of and contributor to CV for a long time (intially during the beta phase) and I find it unclear what is and isn't allowed here. But more so I find the creep towards a more statistical *per se* remit for the site, to wit, @Chl [recently said](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1646/1390)

> It also worth noting that our site policy has evolved since its inception, and we now try to focus on questions that require statistical expertise rather than questions asking about tools, or polls involving shopping-list or extended discussion.

Which alarms me immensely (well, not bit about the polls, discussion of shopping lists). That is **not** what I signed up to with CV originally, and not what I have been contributing to. I also feel that such a move would be to the detriment of CV as a whole. I don't mean to single out @Chl here, but this is as best an admission I could find of what I have grown to believe has been happening here over the past year or so.

Now, I'll admit to not following *all* the meta discussions (here or on Stack Overflow where I am somewhat more active) so I may not have been privy to some of the discussions regarding this shift, but at the very least there seems to be disquiet or a lack of clarity about what CV is and is not.

In a [recent thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1745/1390) on a similar topic @NickCox quoted the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in support of his argument that many R-related questions are off topic here. I quote the relevant section again.

> There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on our sister sites. If your question is about
>
> - **Programming**, ask on Stack Overflow. If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain.

The problem with this "evidence" is that it refers explicitly to "Programming". Just because R is a programming language, it doesn't mean that using R is an act of programming. I would wager that the majority of R Users are not involved in any programming (as most people would recognise the term) but are using it as they would Minitab, Excel, SAS, SPSS etc to run statistical analyses.

If the above is now representative of a broader CV policy, the advice above needs to be updated to removal the *Programming* qualifier.

So my question or perhaps point really, is that the current policy regarding what is on or off topic here needs clarification. But I would like to stimulate a wider debate about what CV aims to be. As I expressed elsewhere, a site devoid of software-related questions is not something I want to see for CV but many users seem to think that anything with "...do this in R?" is OT here.

I reject the argument that if a question is ostensibly related to or about R that it is OT for Cross Validated. If that question is motivated from primarily a statistical point of view then I don't care if it has an R or SAS or SPSS focus. Such questions *should* be on-topic here and I would like to encourage that CV embrace such questions.

For example, this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70188/1390), though it is not the best example it *is* pertinent as the comment by @BabakP about it being OT precipitated my particular question, would (or should) be a useful and relevant contribution here.

P.S. Throughout I have referred to R but you could replace "R" in the above question with Your Favourite Stats Software and my point would remain the same.

Comment: Apologies; it is now late where I am & I post the above just as I am off to bed. I will respond to any questions/comments etc in (hopefully, kids allowing) 7 or 8 hours!

Comment: I agree with you. But it seems that we are a minority. Right now, all `R` or `SAS` or `SPSS` etc questions (however tangentially related to those *as languages*) are being sent to CV. Data analysis is done by packages like this; not all statistics is theory.

Comment: To borrow from a [recent post gung made](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/question-incorrectly-migrated/1758#1758), the basic logic re: this type of OT for me is to ask myself: Can this question be reasonably answered by saying something analogous to "type ______"? If the answer is yes, I close vote. If not, I don't. I strongly disagree with any suggestion that all questions that relate to software, no matter how tangentially are being sent to SO (this is how I parsed Peter's comment, assuming 'CV' was a typo. I could be wrong). Look no further than our most popular tag: `R`.

Comment: By way of follow-up, I have posted a [new Meta question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1780/1390) to curate clearer or more explicit house rules on what is on/off topic for CV. This text could replace the user-visible [What topics can I ask about here?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1780/1390) page in the [Help Centre](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: One worthwhile thing to note is the kinds of questions that SO fields and those it migrates here. What we see migrated to here is almost always far more statistical than what tends to be migrated to there from here (with almost no overlap), and the kind of question we'd be debating over being on topic here is - if posted there instead, almost always simply answered there. That is, in *practice* SO appears on average to be drawing its line about what's on topic there (at least for things initially posted there) quite a bit further into the statistical side than we're discussing here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is on topic on Cross Validated?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/what-is-on-topic-on-cross-validated)

Answer (score 14):

I don't see any real disagreements here.  The key is in the last line: if your interest in any question were to change radically upon replacing `R` by `BMDP` or `Systat` or whatever, then that is likely because the question is not asking anything about data analysis or statistics: it is asking about how to say the magic words to make the software behave.  That's what SO is for.

*Of course* that does not rule out fielding software-related questions here on CV.  As Peter Flom points out in a comment, software is a necessary medium for doing data analysis.  (I have argued elsewhere that it's not a good medium for conveying ideas about data analysis, though, because there is no software platform that a majority of people doing data analysis are familiar with.)  We have always recognized here that many ostensibly software-related questions are, when closely examined, really questions about analyzing data, even though they manifest themselves as software-related problems.  We want to answer *the deeper question* about how to analyze the data rather than the immediate, shallow question about what to change in the code.  This, to me, is one of the keys to writing great questions and providing great answers: a great question provides enough information to identify the root cause of an issue and an awesome answer provides a revelation about that cause, increasing our understanding *regardless of what software platform we may choose to use ourselves.*

I don't think anyone anywhere here has claimed that "using `R` is an act of programming." That's why programming is specifically mentioned in our FAQ.  When you are in fact using `R` *only* for programming, you are employing it in its capacity to do a job that C++ or Python or VBA or whatever could do, and you should prefer to address your question to a community of programming experts.  That ain't us: that's SO.  When you are using `R` to carry out statistical analysis or data visualization, your questions about that are squarely on topic here and always have been.

Recently we have been migrating an average of 2 questions per day (out of 50 per day total) to SO.  They are not all `R`-related: in the list I see a JMP question, a Stata question, and a Java question in the first ten.  What are the `R`-related questions about?

- [How to compute a transition matrix from time series data.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70105)  I disagree with this migration: this question invites answers that explain how to estimate Markov transition matrices and then *illustrate* the procedure with `R`.
- [How to reproduce a paper's results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70051).  Although it *could* be handled in a way that is informative, there seems little prospect that such an approach would appeal to the OP: he just wants the `R` equivalents of Stata commands.
- [This question concerns a package installation problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70063).  That should be of no interest on this site: send it to those who love to diagnose such software problems.
- [Clustering time series by correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70041). This vague question really needed guidance from our community and IMHO is squarely on topic here.  I disagree with its migration.  However, the OP did get a useful answer on SO and her comments there suggest that maybe our community was right in its decision: the discussion is now focusing on details of `R` syntax and not the deeper issue of why this form of analysis is being attempted or how best to do it.  But maybe that's a self-fulfilling result: when a question stays here we discuss the data analysis implications and when it resides on SO, that community naturally addresses syntax, performance, and other computing issues.

I could go on analyzing the migrations, but already some generalities seem to be emerging:

- If we adopt **the approach of addressing every software-specific question as being** (potentially) **a question about data analysis**, in almost all cases we will be right and the question need not be migrated (although it might need considerable improvement to deflect its original focus from `R` to the *application* of `R`).
- If we **pause to write a comment** asking the OP about the nature of their question, we can be confident that we are directing them towards the community best suited to help them.
- **We need to be a little slower to close questions.**  When I review the statistics, I find that many of our community members who are voting to close are spending remarkably little time to make their decisions and some of them are voting far too often for closure.

In brief, when you are in doubt about a question, **don't migrate it, *improve* it!**

Comment: No, that is **not** what [so] is for. As a mod here with the power to migrate to [so] statements such as this are very annoying. Using R is **not** programming. Such questions will get closed immediately on [so] and just clutter up that site. If you don't want those questions here, please don't pass your trash on to someone else. We on [so] could probably do better about sending things here, but only if I knew what was allowed here? Hence my posting.

Comment: Apart from that, I agree with most if not all of the remainder of your answer. That I was motivated to post my semi-rant is evidence that this common sense approach *is not* being followed. Your analysis of recent migrations bears this out too. There is something wrong with the site's advice on what *is* on-topic if several prominent CV people can use it to argue their own, opposite sides in discussions about what is & is not on topic. Also, there doesn't seem to be consistency in this regard from our moderators.

Comment: Finally, I think we need to send a *very clear* signal that comments along the lines of "this is about R, this if OT, post on [so]" are not welcome as the sole, substantive point of the comment. Pointing out how to improve the Q should be at the very least required by the commenter. In general though we (the CV community) just need to be far more consistent & stop requiring that every question be software agnostic or supported by statistical theory in order for it to be on topic.

Comment: The first one should maybe just have been marked as a duplicate. [Here's one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26722/2970), but I'm virtually certain there are others as well. Especially for questions like this, the active community could probably do more to help locate duplicates.

Comment: Gavin, I think you have gone so far in stretching a point that you exaggerate my response beyond recognition. I have never advocated sending "trash" to SO nor have I ever knowingly done such an act. I have strongly agreed that using `R` is not necessarily "programming," but I am still advocating a more nuanced characterization that allows for *some* questions about `R` to be more appropriate for SO than they are here and others to be more appropriate here. It's never a matter of whether I want a question here, but on which site is the better fit (for the OP *and* the SO & CV communities).

Comment: I detect no inconsistency among moderators, BTW, although occasionally we have differences of opinion--and each one of those helps us refine our subsequent actions. Your main point seems to be that you feel confused by our statements about what this site is about. I would like to invite you, then, to turn from ranting--which is useful and appreciated but will soon run its natural course--and instead suggest constructive changes that will clarify for you and others what is considered on topic here. What *should* our FAQ say?

Comment: @whuber My comment on [so] comes from the other side, where things that are OT are regularly pushed to [so]. I would certainly help to rewrite the FAQ or other info. The problem is that needs to be curated and represent the views of the community. Just as I disagree with some users views and find the FAQ inconsistent, what I might propose as the new FAQ would be viewed as inconsistent or disagreeable to others. What is the way to approach this on meta? Should I rewrite something that I disagree with and post that to Meta as a suggested improvement?

Comment: @Gavin I appreciate your engaging with this in such a considerate and thoughtful manner. My belief is that almost any approach you use that (a) gets the ball rolling with a specific suggestion and (b) allows for community discussion is going to be fine. A Meta post would work. I will plead ignorance concerning the concerns within the SO community and therefore wish to thank you in advance for anything you can write that will help me--and perhaps many others here--understand what the issues are on that side, so that we can evolve our policy in a way that respects the needs of CV *and* SO.

Comment: (+1) After having read this, I'm afraid of being guilty of often migrating software-related questions too quickly. I will definitely pay more attention in the future and try to improve the question rather than migrating it immediately.

Comment: I suspect that some disagreements here are less than they seem. But what does it mean that some people are "voting far too often for closure" (quotation from @whuber, usually a model of sagacity)? Aside from any idea that people are voting out of insincerity or idiocy, it seems to me that many votes for closure are based on honest attempts by users with enough reputation to play their part in implementing CV policy! All of a sudden, that is wrong? Naturally I have no problem with people trying to change a policy they think is misguided, but please don't impugn honest differences in view.

Comment: @Nick I thought I would be taken to task for that comment :-), so I appreciate an opportunity to clarify. It is a personal statement expressing my experience of voting *not* to close many questions, inspecting the other votes on the same issues, and finding certain individuals often disagreeing (and in the minority) with the other voters. It also includes inspecting monthly review statistics showing (among other things) how often people vote, how frequently they vote to close, and how much time they spend in their considerations(!). Take it with a grain of salt, but it's still suggestive.

Comment: And no, I am not attempting to impugn honest differences. I just happen to believe that some voters may be rather too eager to close many questions that the community and its moderators find acceptable. It's rather a matter of suggesting that we all need to calibrate our voting and take a little time with our considerations. **To all:** please consider the (oft neglected) options of *editing* to improve questions and *posting comments* encouraging the OPs to improve them.

Comment: In addition, surprisingly or not, I agree with much that @Gavin Simpson says. There are many low-level questions on SO and CV about software that are not, in my view, especially welcome on either site. Gavin said "trash", not a word I would use, but questions that show no discernible research effort are, as I understand it, discouraged on either site. That doesn't imply instant deletion or criticism of the poster, but such posts remain problematic for all with serious commitment to either or both sites.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the extra comment. FWIW, I don't take the comment personally, but I do edit frequently and extensively and do post frequent comments on why posts appear OT, not that more constructive comments yet are not better still. And if something appears OT, the decision can be very quick (and we are all busy people).

Comment: @Nick Yep, I'm among the fastest deciders :-). But there are outliers (in both directions). The low outliers--those who take just a few seconds per decision and make hundreds of decisions, almost all to close--give me pause. I'm not saying anybody is *wrong*; I'm just urging a little self-reflection on us all (myself included). I think any potential problems are being alleviated as more people acquire the reputation and the interest to help out with these tasks, because then nobody need feel that they have to do all the work and we can all trust that others will do it just as well.

Comment: @whuber, I don't know who you're talking about but suspect I may be implicated. I can think of several instances where I've been on the "close" side of a split vote and am not embarrassed to own up to it. The simple fact is: I think this site has a lot of low-quality questions that should be closed/on hold. When I was more active on the site, I tried as much as anyone to encourage the OP to improve the post rather than voting to close but grew discouraged after other high rep users would undermine this effort either by answering the low-quality post or giving it their "OK" in the review queue

Comment: (cont.) as a result, when I do review, I tend to err on the side of closure because I think answering "bad questions" is should be discouraged and putting them on hold is one way to make that happen. During the "hold time" the issues can be sorted out (e.g. by questioning the OP, etc.). BTW, I'm curious how you could "time" the reviews. I often close vote on questions that are not in the review queue, or see a question, think about voting to close, then see it later in the review queue. If your calculation accounts for this then moderators have way more power than I thought :-)

Comment: @Macro Personally, I don't see a problem with answering a poor question - there's even a badge for that if you get sufficient turnaround in voting (or at least there is on [so]) - but I agree with you that using the review tools to pass a poor Q on without comment or improvement defeats the purpose of those privileges.

Comment: @Gavin, if you see the purpose of the site as creating a repository of good questions and answers that will be useful to future visitors (and *not* a site where you serve the OP as though they are a customer) then maybe you can see why I think this behavior defeats the purpose of the site (and why I'm on record railing against it). The main thing is that "bad" questions are often unclear. An exchange involving an unclear question and someone's random guess at what the question was asking is unlikely to be useful to future readers. What's the rush? Why not clarify the question before answering?

Comment: @Macro, I sympathise with this point of view. However, people reach for close far too soon, without opportunity for the OP to modify the question. Random guessing the OPs problem is silly, but what you consider unclear another user may be able to see through the fog because they have specific knowledge. In such cases, the act of answering may clarify the situation allowing others, not just the OP, to update the question. Your approach seems contrary to the SE ethos (unless a Q is irretrievable), regardless of what other CV users think (your comment is currently +3!) :-)

Comment: @whuber I have added a [new Meta Q](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1780/1390) as discussed above.

Comment: Some comments in http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/r-questions-on-topic-for-cv come pretty close to claiming that "using R is an act of programming." Not sure how much it matters in the end but there seem to be some disagreement there.

Comment: To get back to the original issue, here is a good example of what I think belongs to SO: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70315/converting-string-ids-into-numbers-in-a-multilevel-analysis-using-r Although the context of the question was statistical, the question itself is not. I have no strong feelings one way or the other, but from what I can tell questions like these get better answers at SO. On the other hand, questions asking for the usage of statistical software I find on topic, see Gael's posts.

Comment: @gavin, I think we're talking passed each other here so I'm going to stop. I'll just point out a) that putting a question on hold is temporary and does not preclude anything you're saying, b) II never vote to close a question that doesn't clearly go against site policy, and c) pondering how something can be "against SE ethos regardless of what other community members think" makes my head hurt. Also, please call me Macro. I have no idea who Marco is.

Comment: @Macro I'm very, *very* sorry about calling you Marco. I would claim that it was because it was late, but I've had a good nights sleep and still just done it (in a different comment thread).

Comment: I have corrected mispellings. No worries, I'm working on a Mac that offers spelling auto-correction and that's often funny!

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I want to 2nd Macro's points here. In several comments it seems to me you believe putting a question [on-hold] *prevents* the OP from clarifying their Q & users from commenting to get more info. If so, these are not true. Users can comment & OPs can edit their Q after having been put [on-hold]. My impression is that OPs are more likely to edit & provide necessary info when their Q was put [on-hold] than when only a comment requesting such info was made. Moreover, the change from [closed] to [on-hold] was intended to encourage this & make it seem friendlier.

Comment: @gung no, I'm familiar with the on-hold thing. I wasn't in agreement with the who on-hold things when it was being discussed on [so] meta. However it *is* better than what was there before - the questions just got closed. My issue with this is that it still looks like you are voting to close, so what signal does that send? You should leave a comment to explain why, but many people don't. So all we see are close votes. This isn't good for the new user here. I prefer an earlier intervention, especially if a new user, to simply just comment on what is wrong with the Q. I come back...

Comment: (cont) later to close if the OP doesn't improve the Q. (Unless of course there are other reasons to close or other problems with the Q). My issue is that people are voting to close ^ putting Qs on hold inconsistently. You & I seem to have very different opinions about what is on or off topic here regarding software-related Qs. That's fine & it is good to have this debate here on Meta, but it is really bad if users are inconsistently closing Qs whilst others remain open. A new user would be rightfully annoyed if their Q was randomly closed when it was similar to another that escaped scrutiny.

Comment: @Gavin The act of closing produces an automatic message. IMHO this suffices in obvious circumstances such as frankly bad questions or clearly off-topic ones. Closures to migrate and as duplicates are self-evident. In almost all other cases, [a quick search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20closed%3ayes) indicates our community *does* leave comments. However, I agree that some of those comments have recently been inconsistent and confusing; some users--particularly some newer ones--have been suggesting many on-topic questions are not.

Comment: @whuber *some* people leave comments, some people do the right thing. But as I was preparing the proposal I came across posts with close votes that either had no comments, or just one comment but which indicated an inconsistent approach to closing. I didn't mean to give the impression that [stats.se] users weren't commenting in general. This is the trouble with these short comment boxes; there I I was speaking to the *general* issue of the On Hold/Close vote thing on all SE sites. The inconsistency point *was* directed at [stats.se].

Comment: I'll suggest one reason why rushing to close (put on hold), especially in the controversial area of *software-related* questions, is problematic. It precludes anyone with the insight (that could be brought to the table to clarify or draw out the stats issues) from *answering* the Q. They either have to comment and hope the op responds, or edit the question, which takes more time (though perhaps in an ideal world we should expect that they *should* edit the Q), before they can answer. This does happen, esp on [so] where we use chat to organise reopening. Chat isn't used here much though.

Comment: I'd far rather see a good *answer* (one that doesn't speculate as to what the Q is) address both the coding *and* the statistical issues than have no answer. I appreciate that some users will speculate and leave a premature Answer, but that is what voting is for. If the answer is bad or speculative, then it should be downvoted. @macro from your comments for example it seems you prefer to close/put on hold as a means to stop bad answers. I don't see that as a great way to use that power. Use downvotes for bad answers, but rush to on-hold isn't without it's own issues (See prev comment from me).

Comment: Here I disagree somewhat: our community is neither large enough nor active enough for voting to be dispositive in most cases. (I know of many answers that are plainly bad but have several upvotes and mine is the only downvote--but what else can I do without abusing mod powers?) I feel it is far worse to offer even a great answer to your personal (but not explicitly expressed) interpretation of a vague question than to ask for clarification and wait so you can answer a well-formulated question. The reason it can be so bad lies with the high likelihood of misinterpretation of the entire thread.

Comment: @Gavin, I'd like to co-sign whuber's most recent comment but I should clarify: No, I don't prefer to use closure to stop bad answers. After making countless good faith attempts to remedy behavior that I perceive as - to use your words - "against the ethos of SE" by using comments, I see close voting as my only recourse. This is not specific to software related questions; it also refers to users answering blatant duplicates of questions they themselves have answered before (possibly multiple times) and answering questions where no one, including the answerer, knows exactly what's being asked.

Comment: Of course, I accept that this site isn't exactly what I'd like it to be and that's fine. But, it can be irritating to see behavior that appears antithetical to the purpose of SE displayed by high rep users who are then rewarded for it. It's cases like this where healthy detachment from the site is helpful :-) Good luck in the election. Cheers.

Comment: @Whuber your view isn't any different from mine (other than the point about the risk of people closing too quickly). I specifically said that answers making gross assumptions were Bad(TM). I'm well aware of voting, shall we say, idiosyncrasies though more so on [so]. What are you going to do? I always attempt to leave a comment when I downvote so there is a public notice of my disagreement. Beyond that... And, your comment precludes the situation where a Q is unclear to the majority, but may be clear to someone with particular knowledge - that was my case point. Too picky? Probably... :-)

Comment: I think we've gone a bit OT ourselves here. The last round of comments about closing seems stimulated because someone assumed I didn't know what On Hold was and then my comments have been taken out of context. We should probably stop as I think we are far closer in agreement than this comment thread suggests! Thanks for all the input, here and in other Q&As.

Comment: @Gavin (Thanks for helping us better understand your thinking.) No, not too picky at all IMHO.  It is a genuine act of creativity to imagine alternative interpretations of a question and it's too much to suppose that any one of us could possibly imagine all valid interpretations that might come up. I therefore tend to favor actions that help make questions as clear and unambiguous as possible. (This is reflected in the number of comments I have left on this site, almost all of which are efforts to help people improve their questions.)

Comment: Sorry, I said I would stop, but reading back through the comment thread I realised I intended to reply to @whuber pulling me up on my use of "trash". Perhaps it is that I now reside in Canada, or because my partner/wife of 15 years was educated in an American School & has retained many such Americanisms, but all I meant by "trash" was "something not or no longer wanted". I didn't mean anything derogatory about the standard of questions being migrated or to suggest that mods were sending poor questions to [so], only that some things migrated were OT on [so] & quickly deleted there too.

Comment: I don't think that's picky @Gavin. Statistics is an incredibly broad field so I'd never assume that, because it's unclear to me, it's unclear to all. I was restricting focus to cases where the answerer admits they're unsure what the question is asking, e.g. answers like "Well, I'm not sure what you're asking but.." followed by a few very general statements. By the time I read it and consider flagging as "not an answer" it's already upvoted :-) I agree with you that this convo has veered into OT territory and that perhaps we should stop, but this discussion has been entertaining.

Comment: I do see close votes I don't agree with come up fairly often (and I've become less likely to vote to close as I've come to understand the site better). I've found that simply voting against is often much less effective than (i) suggesting to the OP a minor rewording that makes the question more plainly on topic (or even making such a change myself since migration often occurs before the OP has responded) and (ii) discussing why I think it's on-topic (or likely on-topic after clarification) in comments. Sometimes there's disagreement, and I don't think that's a bad thing - we see the reasoning.

Comment: ... people are using. Sometimes something as simple as a re-ordering of paragraphs to place the statistical part first and the language-specific part second appears to be sufficient to prevent some people voting to close.

Answer (score 11):

I don't really know where to post this but there is an additional point that I feel should be made. When looking at questions like

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70310/how-to-fix-mean-and-variance-of-latent-variables-with-the-mirt-package
- How to perform Chi square test for trend in SPSS v 19?
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788051/3-level-logistic-regression
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774985/bootstrap-on-correlation-coefficients-in-r

You need quite a lot of statistics knowledge to even simply *understand* the question. The answer might ultimately be as simple as “type XXX” but finding the right function, being able to understand the relevant documentation and to cut through inconsistent and confusing terminology, or to understand what parameters you need to use and check that the function is really doing what you want is far from trivial.

The wording of the questions might emphasize the “how-do-I-carry-out-test-X” aspect and ostensibly suggest that the relevant statistical decisions have already been made but they still have no place on StackOverflow. Those are simply not questions a programmer could answer.

Obviously, we might still want to close them for other reasons but we should at least agree that the only site where they could possibly be on-topic and stand a good chance of reaching knowledgeable contributors is CrossValidated.

Comment: +1: "Not questions a programmer could [be expected to] answer" sounds like a useful criterion to help us decide about migrations.

Comment: There's a lot of good ideas here. However, I've heard versions of this argument before & I don't really find it compelling. Take a look at some of the [people](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/topusers) who are answering R questions on SO; I don't think they'd be incapable of understanding the statistical content of these questions & answering appropriately. Moreover, although R is a programming language, other languages are typically more appropriate for most programming tasks. The reason people use R is for statistics. Anyone who knows enough R to answer Q's on SO probably knows stats.

Comment: @gung A few of these users are clearly experts in statistics and could certainly understand the questions I listed but it's because they are statisticians or users of statistics, not programmers. Some SO users could perhaps also answer most questions asked here on CV if they chose to but that's not a good reason to ask statistics question there.

Comment: You're right. I don't suggest people should ask *statistics* questions there, but I do think it's fine to ask R *programming* questions there that require "statistical reasoning" to understand.

Comment: For the type of questions I have in mind, there is no algorithm to speak of, no branching, no loops, just a function call. In SPSS the solution could also be to use a specific menu item or change some parameters in a dialog box. In this case, nobody would suggest it's appropriate to ask on SO. But it seems that because R's user interface is primarily text-based, it somehow becomes a “programming” question. As someone who studied computer science before becoming interested in statistics, I still don't see it.

Comment: OK, but then what's the point of moving such questions to a website intended for programmers since answers only require statistics expertise?

Comment: @gung Perhaps if this were phrased "Not questions *the average* programmer could [be expected to] answer", or something to that effect, would that be more suitable? I agree that there are many people on [so] who could answer statistical questions. I see this point as more about making the person asking the question think about the *best* venue for that question.

Comment: What would you think of amending that to "Not questions *the average* `R` programmer could [be expected to] answer", @GavinSimpson? (Are there R-based statistical questions R programmers can't understand?) There is a fundamental ambiguity here which is part & parcel to the trouble we're having defining where the line should be drawn.

Comment: @gung If you question is "Are there *any* R-based statistical questions *some* R programmers can't understand?" the answer to that is clearly yes (I would be a good case in point). (I would `s\understand\answer\ ` tho.) I'm not sure why this is being pulled back to **R** and not stats software *in general*? I take your point that we don't want to suggest [so] users don't know statistical or aren't capable of answering statistical question. My suggestion was to clarify that if you don't think the *average* programmer would be able to answer your question [stats.se] is probably the better venue.

Comment: By "**R**", I mean any such statistical software (eg, Stata, SAS, etc) @GavinSimpson. I am not singling out R for discrimination. I am very fond of R, & use it daily as my software of choice. I am familiar w/ SAS & SPSS, but have mixed feelings about them; I've never used Stata. My point about your version of the quote is that the "average programmer" probably develops software in C++ for commercial clients w/o any knowledge of even what a t-test is. But if you think of the *average `R <Stata, possibly SAS, etc>` programmer* understands about stats it's a whole different ball game.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans, you are raising a good point. I am becoming much clearer, as a result of the ongoing discussion, that just because a question is only about how to use statistical software doesn't mean it's a *programming* question, & that such questions are off-topic on SO under a fairly strict definition of "programming" (that essentially mirrors my somewhat strict definition of "stats"). The result of this is that such questions would be off-topic for *both* CV & SO. Those questions are essentially *tech support* for software & probably belong on the r-help listserve (statalist, etc).

Comment: @gung Good point, but [so] primarily *is* filled with C, C++, JAVA, etc programmers - the R tag is relative small there. Hence my point was that [stats.se] would probably be a better place if the *average* programmer might not understand or be able to answer the Q. There may well be R programmers on [so] who could answer, but when deciding on where to post, [stats.se] may be better as you might get different eyes on the problem that you wouldn't get if you just focus on the **R** programming side of one's question.

Comment: Do the C++ programmers on SO answer the R questions, @GavinSimpson? When I'm on SO (which is relatively little), my impression is that SO is an archipelago of relatively isolated islands. Ie, the C++ programmers *never* answer the R questions & R users (or at least I) never read the C++ Qs.

Comment: Sometimes @gung [\*]. But you are missing the point! Just because *some* programmers, **R** or otherwise, *could* answer the question, doesn't make that question on-topic for [so] or off-topic for [stats.se]. ([*] in fact, sometimes some very good answers or comments or insights come from people outside the R tag, who happen to see a question because of other tags were added to the Q.)

Comment: Just to throw in some numbers: The easiest things to count are tags. For R, CV tags are 4556, SO are 37354; for SAS, CV tags are 234, SO are 1550; for Stata, CV tags are 283 and SO tags are 466; for SPSS, CV tags are 557 and SO tags are 296. Clearly these numbers say nothing about (0) the detail of any posts (1) which site was more appropriate for posts (2) fraction of any or good answers (3) anything else, but the variation in ratio is quite striking.

Comment: I miss lots of points, @GavinSimpson, it's one of my hobbies. I think you're right that just b/c the typical R programmer could answer a Q doesn't mean it's on-topic for SO (cf, my response to Gael above).

Comment: @gung Well, I think we could, to some extent, accommodate these usage questions here but I understand I am probably more lenient than most in this respect. In any case, some are indeed essentially tech support questions (didn't think of that term before but that's really what it is). We should decide for ourselves whether we want to close, welcome or improve them but not believe they should be asked on SO merely because software or code is involved.

Comment: @gung In your response to Gaël, can I clarify what you mean by "questions [that] are essentially tech support for software"? In the [proposed](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1781/1390) On Topic text I specifically mention a point about *General stats software use*. I need to tidy the language there, but are you referring to those questions in you comment or *all* questions on the use of statistical software? Just trying to clarify where you stand in relation to the proposed text and my viewpoint.

Comment: That's difficult in comments, @GavinSimpson. Ultimately, I'm going to need to proffer an answer there, but I've been dragging my feet. However, your distinction b/t what would constitute off-T "general stats software use" & other "software-related" questions that would be on-T, isn't clear for me. I can say (cf above) that I do not think the idea that a Q requires "statistical reasoning" to answer makes it on-topic. My basic criterion is *What does the OP need explained*? If it's a statistical concept, it's on-T, if it's something about software & they understand the stats issue, it's off-T.

Comment: Another data point: [the top-voted R questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=votes&pageSize=15) do not require *any* statistical knowledge whatsoever (save for one or two that were closed!). They are all questions about core language constructs, sorting and processing data, etc. that could just as well be asked about Python or SQL.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that the line between on-topic and off-topic has drifted a little bit lately, and it'd be nice if we could (collectively) re-establish it.

I wanted to second @whuber's point that most software questions that might be off-topic have underlying data analysis questions with two examples:

1. I once asked about why the [distance values differed between SPSS's and R's dendrograms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44957/does-spss-rescale-dendrograms). It turned out to be something fairly mundane (an artefact from when SPSS drew ASCII diagrams), but at the time I was wondering whether the rescaling had some potentially-useful statistical interpretation.
2. I also recall a question about adjusting the priors on a Naive Bayes classifier in R. This could be answered in several different ways. The "StackOverflow-y" answer is probably either

   - "Add these arguments to the function call, like so...."
   - "You can't in $X$; use package $Y$ instead."

   However, armed with (a very little bit of) statistical knowledge, one could suggest multiplying the posterior probabilities of each class $P(\textrm{Class}=C|\textrm{Data})$ by $\frac{P_{new}(C)}{P_{old}(C)}$ to manually update the priors instead.

While I don't want to wade through tons of "how do I import my Excel file into R?" or "why does my NumPy matrix look weird?", I'd personally like the line to be drawn such that these sorts of questions are firmly on the on-topic side.

Even some of the "How can I do this, but in another language" questions may have merit, as some techniques have far too many names (there are probably about a dozen ways of saying "PCA"), and sometimes a term is overloaded to mean multiple things.

Maybe the rule of thumb should be something like "How often would this happen in a non-statistical context?" Everybody has programming problems with things like I/O and flow control, but I would venture to guess that there are very few off-topic situations where someone would care about potential differences between Matlab's `eig` function and Octave's `qz`

Comment: +1 (but only now having a chance to comment). I tried to work @whuber's point into the proposal I posted in the other Meta thread. I could add another example from your Answer here too. Thanks.